# Как бы teamcity заставить видеть закрывающиеся PR`ы?

Tags: github, docker, teamcity

При создании PR`а можно заставить teamcity запустить build, сборку, например указав путь до скрипта (докеры собрать, к примеру), как бы отследить закрытие PR, подставив ему другой нужный скрипт? Чтобы те же самые докеры гасить.
Можно ли вообще в теории такое?

Comment: а почему бы не разделять PR, и бранч, куда сливают, например, мастер?

Comment: дополните вопрос, пожалуйста. непонято какую задачу хотите решить

Comment: Задача? Чтобы при закрытии PR`а сворачивалось окружение, поднятое на докере. Собственно, задачу уже решили по средствам настройки вебхука на github и дёрганья php-скрипта